Ecwid JS for adding and removing products from cart based on customer input
I am having trouble updating my cart through JS body input.  I want to update the cart based on a customer input into a text field.  The customEngraving variable is pricing for a product I have already created on Ecwid and each index translates to a price point.  I am new to the Ecwid API so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ecwid.OnAPILoaded.add(function(page) {
    var customEngraving = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17]
    var customInput = document.querySelector('CSSSelector'); 

    if (customInput) {
        customInput.addEventListener('input', async function() {
            try {
                
                var engravingProduct=await getEngravingProduct();
                const items = Ecwid.Cart.get().items;
                // if there is an engraving in the cart, remove it
                for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                    if (items[i]['id']=='207127971') {
                        Ecwid.Cart.removeProduct(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // add engraving to cart
                const ind=customEngraving[customInput.value.length];
                var charCount=engravingProduct['options'][2]['choices'];
                var newChoices = [charCount[ind]];
                engravingProduct['options'][2]['choices']=newChoices;
                Ecwid.Cart.addProduct(engravingProduct);

            } catch (error) {console.error('Error processing input:', error);}
        });
    }
});

async function getEngravingProduct() {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'MyToken'}
      };
    
      try { 
        const response = await fetch('url', options)
        const obj = await response.json();
        return obj;
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }  
  }

I have made sure that the getEngravingProduct() function works as well as the section where the correct product is being added to the cart.  I think I might be getting tripped up by the Ecwid syntax, but any and all help is appreciated.
